# how to turn off link preview in Outlook 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Whenever I add a url link in a message body, Outlook 365 adds a preview of the web site.

I can click on disable preview; how do I disable this feature by default?

Answer (score 5):

You can disable this per user
Go to Options > Layout > "Link Preview" 
disable this and this will remove the option for each user

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, you can't: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/235368.aspx
But you can send feedback to them there.

Comment: This may have since changed, as @Adam 's answer points out, also the link is now dead.